# calling memset from x86_64 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, abi

I'm trying to learn x86 assembly, by looking at the generated assembly from clang.  For instance, I'd like to learn how an automatic array in C is initialized to all 0's.

```
int64_t my_array [3000] = {0};
```

It looks like the assembly is reserving 24000B on the stack ( 3000 * 64b / 8B/b ) then calling memset.  From memset's man page, it's signature looks like:

```
void *
memset(void *b, int c, size_t len);
```

So I know that the second argument should be passed in %rsi is 0 (the value I want every byte set to), and the third argument (%rdx) to be $24000, but what about the first argument (%rdi)?  The two relevant instructions from the generated assembly appear to be:

```
leaq  -24016(%rbp), %rax
movq  %rax, %rdi
```

but I don't understand why negative 24016 from the base pointer? Why store in %rax then immediately move to %rdi (maybe because I just didn't compile with optimizations)?

Either way, I'm not sure how to pass the address of the first byte of the array to memset.  I'm on OSX too, so I've already had to offset my stack pointer by 8B to assemble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have allocated `my_array` on the stack (automatic storage), this means the compiler has to decrement the stack pointer (the stack grows towards lower addresses) by the size of your local variables plus room to save registers and such.  The `%ebp` base pointer is set to point to the frame pointer of the caller (after saving the caller's base pointer by pushing it on the stack).  This is part of the convention necessary for proper stack unwinding.  See Chapter 9 *Exception handling and stack unwinding* in Agner Fog's comprehensive Calling Conventions document

http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf.

Since `%ebp` is pointing to the caller's frame, the compiler uses a negative offset from it to point to the beginning of `my_array`, a local variable in the called function.

I don't have an answer as to why the compiler stored the address in `%rax` and immediately copied it to `%rdi`, it seems it could have done that in one step

```
leaq  -24016(%rbp), %rdi
```

Comment: I don't understand the -24016 part though, seems arbitrary.  Negative since stack grows towards lower memory address, and 24000 as that's how much *I* need, but why the extra 16B?  %ebp is 32b so would only need 4B?

Comment: See Chapter 5 *Stack Alignment* in same document, it says "The 64 bit systems keep the stack aligned by 16. The stack word size is 8 bytes, but the stack must be aligned by 16 before any call instruction. ... A procedure can rely on these rules when storing XMM data that require 16-byte alignment. This applies to all 64 bit systems (Windows, Linux, BSD).

Comment: I'm still at a loss for the -24016.  My intuition still would be to use -24000.  In fact, 24000 is a multiple of 16 (24000 / 16 == 1500).  Still, I'm storing the address of space allocated on the stack, not messing with the stack pointer (rsp) 's alignment.

Comment: @NickDesaulniers: You are right, it isn't clear.  Would you post the disassembly for the entire function? It would be easier to try to understand what the compiler is doing.

Comment: @NickDesaulniers - I haven't forgotten - been busy - will take a look this evening

Comment: Of the 24032B allocated on the stack, I think the compiler chose to start the reference at -24016(%rsp).  From looking elsewhere, it looks like the compiler has leeway when choosing where to place automatic variables on the stack, as long as they're aligned.

Comment: @NickDesaulniers, yes, I agree.  So far what I've concluded is: after pushing %ebp on the stack the stack is 16 byte aligned, assuming it was 16 byte aligned prior to the call, that is because you now have two 8-byte items on the stack, the return address, and %ebp.  It looks like there is some magic going on due to ___stack_chk_guard, which means code was compiled with clang -fstack-protector, I dont' fully understand that yet.

Comment: stack check guards prevent stack buffer overflow.  If the comparison fails the process bails.  Anyways, thanks for your help.  This is the project that I'm working on: https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/bf_interpreter_jit_compiler